# How to make query that ignores undefined variables?

Tags: php, mysql

How make mysql search defined just by what is written in html form, by user, and if some form box is stayed empty, mysql should ignore it. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE name= '".$name."' AND publisher = '".$publisher."' ";
mysql_query($sql);
```

This query will display all rows where name and publisher are together. Now, what if user insert just name, and left publisher box empty. The idea is that php/mysql ignore empty form box, and display every row with inserted name. But it will not do that because $publisher will be undefined, and error emerges. How to tell musql to ignore $publisher? More generally, the question is: how to generate query that make searching defined by certain criteria if they exists, and if they don't how to just ignore it?

Comment: And if users want to inject their own query, then let them do it too...

Comment: you need to validate the inputs and build the query with a series of if statements (or switch case) before hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up the sql programmatically. I am assuming you have escaped the values properly.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog";

$wheres = array();
if (!empty($name)) {
    $wheres[] = " name = '$name'";
}
if (!empty($publisher)) {
    $wheres[] = " publisher = '$publisher'";
}

if (count($wheres)) {
    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $wheres);
}

//RUN SQL
```

Also have a read through [this](http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases), you are using a deprecated mysql library.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow either the name or the publisher to be `NULL`.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE (name= '".$name."' OR name IS NULL) AND (publisher = '".$publisher."' OR publisher IS NULL)";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$my_var = " ";
if($publisher)   //if(!empty($publisher))
   $my_var = " AND publisher =  '".$publisher."' ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE name= '".$name."' ".$my_var;
```

if the publisher is empty then you need to pass the `NULL` value and PLZ note that it is a bad practise.It will causes many sql injection issues.Try to put validations for the things

Comment: but you cant compare equal operator with null in sql